# Como deixar NULL caso $_POST esteja vazio no banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Há alguma forma que eu possa deixar como *null* os campos que não foram preenchidos? Na criação da tabela, os campos já foram definidos como `DEFAULT NULL`, porém ao fazer o *insert* — no banco de dados *MySQL* — por *$_POST*, os campos que não foram preenchidos continuam vazios.

Abaixo esta o código.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $nome          = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome     = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $nivel         = $_POST['nivel'];
    $date     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $_SESSION['warning']['type']    = "success"; // tipos success, info, warning e error
    $_SESSION['warning']['message'] = "Player Created Successfully!"; // mensagem que vai aparecer

    if (empty($_POST['nome'])) {
        $_SESSION['warning']['type']    = "error"; // tipos success, info, warning e error
        $_SESSION['warning']['message'] = "The NAME is required."; // mensagem que vai aparecer
        echo "history.go(-1);";
        exit;
    }

    $vsl = "INSERT INTO `files` (`id`, `nome`, `sobrenome`, `nivel`, `date`)VALUES(NULL, '$nome', '$sobrenome', '$nivel', '$date')";
    $rsl = mysqli_query($conn, $vsl);

    header("Location: add.php");
    exit();

}
```

Comment: O mais recomendado é você usar prepared statement do mysqli, com isso seu problema será resolvido sem precisar ficar fazendo if em todas as variáveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como esta inserindo via PHP aspas simples é diferente de null uma idéia é colocar em variavel o conteudo exemplo:

```
$sobrenome = strlen($sobrenome) > 0 ? "'$sobrenome'" : "NULL";
$vsl = "INSERT INTO files (id, nome, sobrenome, nivel, date) VALUES(NULL, '$nome', $sobrenome, '$nivel', '$date')";
$rsl = mysqli_query($conn, $vsl);
```

Isso resolveria.

Comment: Fiz o exemplo apenas no campo $sobrenome mas pode ser feito em todos.